# Whats the best way to start programming for my non-smartphone?

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, mobile-phones

I have a general old-fashioned phone that has no special app system and uses Java (I assume ME) for the few applications you can use on it.

This is still a decent userbase and I'd like to start programming for this type of phone.  I already know basic Java theory and syntax, so.. where do I get started for programming for non-smartphones?

Comment: I use one of these phones and care about applications =\  So by that same regard there must be other such people.  People who can't really afford the upfront or monthly cost of a Smartphone  (People like me).

Comment: What are you trying to do from your phone?  Those phones aren't powerful enough to do anything ... it would be better to find a way to get a smart phone wo data plan and write applications for that.

Comment: @Nix: you can make decent flashlight app for J2ME phones with big screen, although, can't find more uses...

Comment: @Nix: A smart phone without a data plan? Where does such a thing exist?


@Navarr: I'm with you on wanting apps without high monthly costs.

Comment: @DLH: I want to put foursquare on my phone using the GPS since Opera Mini doesn't support the javascript.  There is a facebook app and a twitter app and google maps apps for free on my phone.

I'm using a Virgin Mobile Rumor Touch for $25/m (Unlimited Text, Unlimited Web, 300 minutes).  And I want foursquare on it if I have to write it myself, lol.

Comment: If your looking tutorials see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584923/do-you-know-a-good-j2me-tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best programming environment for Java ME IMO is Eclipse with EclipseME.  Includes lots of built-in stuff about packaging your midlets etc.  The SonyEricsson wireless toolkit is great for PC-based testing and debugging, but don't forget on-device testing!

If you don't know much about Java ME's lifecycle, then get reading as widely as you can, and try lots and lots of examples.  Start with the JSR-118 (MIDP2) javadocs; you'll want these open on your desktop at all times while coding.

Don't waste too much time with the form-based user-interface; I recommend either rolling your own using Canvas, or read about LWUIT.

You can do all sorts in Java ME and target a very broad range of handsets.  HTTP capability is guaranteed, so you can hook up to a public web service, or create your own using something like Google Appengine.

Finally, you can release your app very easily on somewhere like Get Jar.  Don't be put off by those who say "no owners of Java ME handsets want apps", you'll find the most popular user bases on this site will be users in countries such as India and Indonesia.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I would start with a book on J2ME and work from there.

Try [Beginning J2ME: From Novice to Professional](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590594797).

You could also download the [J2ME SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/downloads/sdk30-jsp-139759.html) and play around with the example they give.

For tutorials have a look at the stackoverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584923/do-you-know-a-good-j2me-tutorial as mention in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

I started with writing simple Flashlight application (choose how much seconds screen will remain lit) in NetBeans ME. And other app which I mange was Countdown with some graphics and sound. After that I found limitations too much annoying and now I'm waiting for my Android phone.

**in short:**
If you want to try it out - you don't need to buy books. There are plenty of tutorials around.
But, if you want to start *deep* development - don't waste time.

Comment: I don't mind wasting some time with quick little hello world esque applications.  I'm not skilled enough in Java to just jump straight up into it.  Theres lots of learning to be done, after all.

Comment: As a further note, I'm kind of looking for help finding those tutorials.  Google is great and all, but I know Developers generally tend to remember the tutorials that really helped them out.

Comment: Well, I just made UI in designer and filled in some code... Didn't really use any tut, but there were maaany guesses... EDIT: JAVA is not my strong side